# I have a html file(which is my cv) in my disk and i need a web link for it to give it to a recruiter

Tags: html, web

I tried uploading to some file hosting sites, but all I get is a download link. I need a web page, which when opened will display my html page. 
Locally, my Url is *file:///C:/Users/Srinath/Downloads/My%20CV%20updated.html*

Comment: Have you considered saving the CV as an image and uploading it to an image hosting site?

Comment: They require it to be a PDF, doc or docx. My idea was to convert it to a pdf. But most free html to pdf converters require a link and don't support file uploading.

Comment: You can print a html as a pdf file in e.g. Chrome; then you can publish it online.

Comment: I tried using adobe acrobat dc Convert web page to PDF. It seems broken in every browser for me. Pdfcrowd's extension says it doesn't support conversion of local URLs

Answer (score 0):

So you want to host an html page?
https://www.biz.nf/web-hosting.php 
it's free, you have limited storage and a .co.nf instead of .com on your domain, but for a free domain and storage it's not bad.